# can we pass workflow input argument value from javascript in CRM 2015

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2015

Is there any way to pass input argument value to CRM workflow before calling workflow in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the value of a field that is only used for that workflow so yes. What you should have a look at is what you are trying to accomplish and see if it's a sound architectural decision.